# Google cloud - json ключ в Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, google-cloud

Есть .NETCore приложение, оно пользуется Google сервисами через SDK Google Cloud Translation

Никакой авторизации внутри приложения нет, просто код для перевода

```
 TranslationClient client = TranslationClient.Create();
                    var response = client.TranslateText(
                        text: phrase,
                        targetLanguage: endLanguage,
                        sourceLanguage: startLanguage);
```

Чтобы ими пользоваться, надо скачать с гугл консоли ключ в формате .json, и затем в системных переменных среды указать к нему путь

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = C:/Key.json
```

Оно работает на Windows 10 из Visual Studio, но на проде у меня Убунта, на ней докер, и в докере это .NETCore приложение.

Как мне указать к нему путь из докера? Могу этот файл положить в корень проекта, тогда он будет внутри докера, но доступ через переменную среды это не сделает. Может есть возможность как то указать гуглу прямой доступ на файл из проекта, не через переменную среды?

Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp.App.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./MyApp.App.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.App.dll"]
```

Comment: а вы пробовали упаковать/примотрировать ваш файл в контейнер и настроить переменные окружения для него с правильным путем к файлу внутри контейнера?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Возможно это то что мне и нужно, но я не знаю как это сделать. Поместить файл в контейнер я могу, но добавить переменную внутри докера - как? И какой там путь будет? Если у меня путь внутри windows

C:\Users\user\app\wwwroot\key.json

То какой будет внутри докера?

Comment: добавьте Dockerfile, пожалуйста

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Добавил в вопрос, благодарю вас!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для передачи ключа в контейнер существую разные способы.

Можно передать переменную окружения и файл без изменения `Dockerfile`, а при запуске/создании контейнера. Например:

```bsh
docker run -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/key.json -v $(pwd)/key.json:/key.json <остальные параметры>
```

Это приведет к тому, что в контейнере при помощи параметра `-v $(pwd)/key.json:/key.json` будет примотрирован файл с ключем по пути `/key.json`. И соответственно добавлена переменная окружения `-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/key.json`.

Можно в `Dockerfile` добавить переменную окружения сразу (чтобы не добавлять её при каждом запуске), но все ещё монтировать файл. Например:

```
...

FROM base AS final
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/key.json

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.App.dll"]
```

Теперь его можно запускать так:

```bsh
docker run -v $(pwd)/key.json:/key.json <остальные параметры>
```

Но можно также и файл с ключем добавить в итоговый образ (Dockerfile), такой подход подойдет для разработки или тестирования, но лучше его не использовать на реальном приложении (секретную информации лучше не добавлять в образ, его оттуда легко достать).

```
...

FROM base AS final
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/key.json
COPY key.json .

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.App.dll"]
```

Тогда запускать контейнер можно командой, которую вы использовали раньше, никаких доп. параметром не нужно.